# Prevent Google using my site in featured snippet result

Tags: google-search, search-results

I have noticed in the past few months that traffic to the QA section of my site has plummeted. The vast amount of the 300+ pages here rank quite well in Google and I am not doing anything to cheat the system. I decided to do a few searches and I have found that almost every page is now the [featured snippet](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6229325?hl=en) for the search result and the answer to most of the questions are featured in the snippet, meaning the user never needs to visit my site.

I can understand how this benefits the user, but how does it benefit me, the person who is putting time and effort into publishing the content?

Is there a way to prevent Google from using snippets from my website in this way? Is there even any legal grounds to this? If I were to take "snippets" from other websites that gave the user the answer they needed, I would likely get hit with a copyright notice for plagiarism.

Answer (score 1):

You can disallow Google to show snippets for your results, which affects all kind of snippets (featured as well as normal!):

- For Google only:

  ```html
  <meta name="googlebot" content="nosnippet">
  ```
- For all search engines (that support it):

  ```html
  <meta name="robots" content="nosnippet">
  ```

Instead of HTML, you can also use the HTTP header `X-Robots-Tag`.

Google’s documentation: [Meta tags that Google understands](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en)

---

Google doesn’t seem to offer a way to disallow only featured snippets.

If you want to keep normal snippets and avoid featured snippets, the only option you have is to change your markup in such a way that Google is no longer able to detect and extract the information. As Google doesn’t document how the feature works, you would have to guess/try.